# response stream instead of response String, Jaxws

Tags: jax-ws

How can I get a stream in JaxWS while reading the response from a URL? My problem is that I get the URL response as a 500 MB data. So I am looking for a response stream which I can save directly into a file.

```
final MyBean myBean = new MyBean("posted MyBean", 11);
Response response = webTarget.path("resource").request("application/xml")
    .post(Entity.entity(myBean, "application/xml"));

System.out.println(response.getStatus());
final String responseEntity = response.readEntity(String.class);
System.out.println(responseEntity);
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer myself. We can get the stream as below:-

```
InputStream in = response.readEntity(InputStream.class);
```